# Почему «не покладая рук» пишется раздельно с «не»?

Tags: орфография, фразеология, частица-не, деепричастия

Недавно встретился с фразеологизмом "не покладая рук" и удивился тому, что частица "не" пишется раздельно. Проверил и на Грамоте.Ру, и в солидном орфографическом словаре. Всё так.
Но ведь деепричастие "покладая" не существует. В подобных случаях (негодуя, недоумевая) частица "не" пишется слитно, ибо без нее слово не употребляется.
Возможно, кто-то из знатоков русского языка может подсказать, в каком источнике дается объяснение этому феномену?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 — Нельзя складывать (= покладать) руки и ничего не делать! 

 — Я так отдыхаю!

 — Часто очень отдыхаешь. Другие без перерыва работают.
```

Итак, *работать **не покладая рук*** — это работать, ***не складывая рук,*** то есть **НЕПРЕРЫВНО.** Раздельное написание устаревшей **ФОРМЫ** глагола отсюда понятно. Это  отрицание **действия**: нельзя сидеть ***сложа руки.***

Для сравнения: работать **спустя рукава** (неодобр.) – работать, делать что-либо **небрежно**, кое-как.  Другими словами, работать **ПЛОХО.**

Большой толково-фразеологический словарь Михельсона:
**руки складывать** (иноск.) — **бездействовать.**  Ср. (Ввиду частых пожаров) **нельзя складывать** руки... принятие мер предосторожности... возможно осуществить немедленно.

**[Происхождение фразеологизма](https://na-dostupnom.ru/rabotat-ne-pokladaya-ruk/)**

*В народе работой в полном смысле слова всегда считался именно физический труд. **Руки** наших предков **не знали покоя**: рубили, строили, запрягали, шили, штопали, молотили, косили, удили… Всего и не перечислить!*

*В добрую пору крестьянин не знал ни минуты отдыха. Вот и приходилось **работать не покладая (то есть, не складывая) рук.** А вот те, кто сидел «сложа ручки», могли и без хлеба остаться.*

*Обратите внимание: запятая **внутри фразеологизма** не ставится. Да, здесь присутствует деепричастный оборот, но в границах **идиоматического выражения** он не обособляется.*

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

К какому виду по классификации Виноградова можно отнести фразеологизм ***не покладая рук?***

**Фразеологический словарь:** Экспрес. Не переставая, без устали, усердно (трудиться, делать что-либо).

Это скорее **идиома**. Смысл сочетания *не покладая рук* в современном языке **неясен**: прикладывать руки, класть руки — что это значит?

А ***работать не покладая рук*** — это идиоматическое сочетание, включающее идиому *не покладая рук*.

Comment: Вечер добрый, *Sharon*. Думаю, что в цитируемой статье имеется ошибка. *Да, здесь присутствует причастный оборот...*

Comment: Надо деепричастный оборот, да. Главное, что она верна по СУЩЕСТВУ: не покладая рук – это не складывая руки.  А сидеть сложа руки тоже нельзя.  Одно и тоже действие в двух пословицах. Но если что, то я ответ уберу, если он кому-то еще покажется лишним.

Comment: Дорогие друзья! Все, что написано в ответ на мой вопрос, интересно и расширяет кругозор. Однако я советовался с вами по другому поводу. Все приведенные примеры прекрасно разъясняют смысл выражения "не покладая рук" .Но все эти примеры содержат деепричастия с непременной частицей "нет". Нет ни одного примера, где бы слово "покладая" было написано без предшествующей ему частицы "не". Именно это меня смущает, поэтому считаю, что  "непокладая" следовало бы писать слитно с частицей "не", ибо слово без "не" не употребляется (нет слова "покладая")

Comment: В русской орфографии возможно раздельное написание устаревших слов. Таких примеров много среди наречий:  § 137. Пишутся раздельно: 1. Наречные сочетания предлогов-приставок без, для, до, под, при, про с формами имен существительных (в том числе не употребляющимися вне этих сочетаний), напр.:  без обиняков, без продыху, без просыпа, без удержу, без умолку, без устали, до зарезу, до НЕузнаваемости.

Comment: Причина – падежное управление как более сильный фактор.   В нашем случае причина – явное отрицание действия, выраженного устаревшей ФОРМОЙ глагола. При этом сам глагол просматривается  ясно.

Comment: Дорогие друзья! Спасибо большое за то, что заинтересовались моим вопросом и предложили глубокие и детальные интерпретации. Особенно теплые слова благодарности - уважаемой мною много лет  Sharon. Именно Ваш ответ с двумя последними комментариями дают полное и мотивированное разъяснение сформулированной мною проблемы.

Comment: Спасибо большое за приемку ответа, ваш вопрос правилен и интересен. А ваш фразеологизм оказался настолько интересным, что мы до сих пор стараемся определить его вид.  И если это фразеологическое единство, то в чем его метафоричность и образность?)

Answer (score 2):

Раздельно, потому что идиома. Глагол "покладать" устарел.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: См. https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%98%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0&mode=all&l=1

Comment: Галина, ау-у… 

Comment: https://uchi.ru/otvety/questions/prochitay-zapishi-znachenie-frazeologizma-rabotat-ne-pokladaya-ruk-i-sostav-s-nim-predloz Ой! Я не поняла; думала, что оспаривается идиома, а речь об ошибке! Спасибо!