# Не покладая рук — какой вид фразеологизма?

Tags: фразеология

1. Этот **фразеологизм** обсуждался на форуме в **[другой теме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478856/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5)** и был назван **идиомой.**

Вполне возможно, что это так: эта грамматическая форма глагола  сейчас не используется. Мне же непонятна и его **семантика** тоже: речь идет о глаголе ***положить*** (покладывать) руки, а куда их положить? Есть версия, что имеется в виду **сложить (складывать**) руки, но не положить же. Или когда-то так говорили?

2. Интересно, что  Грамота.ру даже не вносит сочетание во **фразеологический** словарь, оно есть только в **словаре синонимов** к слову ***постоянно***.
3. Так **идиома** это (фразеологическое сращение) или **другой вид** фразеологизма. В каких **источниках** можно найти подтверждение? Во фразеологических **словарях** вид фразеологизма **не определяется**, например:

**Бить  баклуши** (неодобр.) – бездельничать, заниматься пустяковым делом, праздно шататься. Наиболее распространенной версией происхождения этого **фразеологизма** считается следующая...  [Справочник по фразеологии](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8&mode=all&l=1https://). А по классификации Виноградова это вроде бы **идиома** (фразеологическое сращение).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При рассмотрении фразеологизмов, нужно иметь в виду, что порой граница между фразеологическими сращениями и фразеологическими единицами зыбкая.

Так в пособии Лексика русского языка, 1971.  А. В. Калинин., подробно описываются фразеологизмы.

Вот что говорится.

При классификации фразеологических словосочетаний нередко возникают затруднения, связанные с тем, что некоторые устойчивые выражения находятся как бы на полпути от единств с к сращениям.   И языковеды, и студенты на занятиях по фразеологии по-разному определяют тип фразеологизмов, к которому относятся обороты ***положить зубы на полку,*** ***сесть в калошу,*** с***емь пятниц на неделе*** и некоторые другие.
Трудности зачисления оборота в сращения или в единства возникают и в тех случаях. когда, с одной стороны, чувствуется образность  и некоторая мотивированность значения словосочетания ( а стало быть, и тяготения к фразеологическим единствам), а с другой стороны, в обороте есть какое-то не совсем обычное слово или несовременная грамматическая форма ( а это — признак фразеологического сращения). Например: (работать) **спустя рукава**,  **от мало до велико,** на бос**у** ногу, средь бела дня, **беречь про черный день,** **Спустя**  — не обычная, не принятая в литературной речи форма деепричастия от глагола спустить(правильнее: спустив), словосочетания **от мала до велика.** **на босу ногу**, **средь бела** дня содержат формы косвенных падежей кратких прилагательных ( **а в современном языке краткие прилагательные не склонятся**); предлог про в выражении беречь про черный день имеет устаревшее значение ( **для, на, т. е. предлог цели, ср. про запас**). И все же мы должны отнести подобные словосочетания к фразеологическим единствам: образность, метафоричность, этих оборотов речи перевешивает,побеждает неправильности, имеющихся в них.

Подытоживая вышесказанные, становится ясно, что и фразеологизм (работать) **не покладая рук** тоже относится к фразеологическим единствам.
**Покладая**  — не обычная, не принятая в литературной речи **форма действ.деепричастия  наст. вр. от неупотр. глаг. покладать.**

Comment: Серж, спасибо большое за ответ (интересный у вас материал), голос от меня. Значит, у нас все-таки единство, а не сращение. Я вот тоже думаю, что до идиомы «не покладая рук» не дотягивает. Но почему Грамота. ру даже не поместило словосочетание в свой "Словарь по фразеологии", вот это мне непонятно. И еще вопрос по семантике «покладать». Это ведь несов. вид от "покласть", а  в соврем. языке от  «положить»? Понятно, что нельзя сидеть «сложа руки», а сидеть и при этом «покласть руки» тоже нельзя? Что это значит, куда «покласть руки»? Есть здесь образность и необычность?

Comment: Но это дополнительные вопросы, поэтому я принимаю ответ.

Comment: Можно говорить о стертости  метафоры. Ведь здесь имеется в виду переносное значение.

Answer (score 1):

"Не покладая рук" — это форма не от "положить", а от "покладать". Видовая пара "покласть - покладать".

Абсолютной идиомой это вроде как не назвать, поскольку значение этого фразеологизма "усердно, напряжённо" всё-таки окончательно от значений слов, его составляющих, не обособилось.

Короче, степень идиоматизации тут не стопроцентная, и семантическая мотивированность этого фразеологизма всё-таки очевидна: не покладая рук, то есть не опуская руки, не отдыхая, будучи в напряжении, усердно, напряжённо.

Работать ***не покладая рук*** - фактически оборот-то наречием является, точнее, выступает как аналог определительного наречия, как наречная группа со значением качества действия. Сравните это с адвербиализированными деепричастиями типа *молча, крадучись, сидя* и т. д.

Можно считать этот оборот "фразеологическим единством", т. е. цельным оборотом, но в той или иной степени мотивированным значением входящих в него слов.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ и интерес к теме, голос от меня.  Прочитав еще раз ответы, я решила, что тема мне еще недостаточно ясна. Нашла в Сети интересный материал, позже дам свой ответ.

Comment: Я не понял: теперь это мёртвый форум? Никто ничего не пишет? Форум одного активного человека - Sharon?

Comment: Теперь нас двое активных, поэтому я вам так благодарна за ответы. А в этой теме даже трое.  А там, глядишь, и другие подтянутся)